# CFGRID vertical scrollbar and restricted visible records

Tags: coldfusion

I am working on coldfusion 10 and i have the following requirement,

How I need to display 100 records in first page with 18 records visible and remaining 82 records visible  should be through scroll bar.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please put your code here. This may be helpful for us.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an encapsulation thing. You provided no code in your question so I am going to do the best here conceptually.

You will have a query that selects 100 records using `<cfquery>`

I am not sure your SQL base so you can  limit it with `<cfquery>` and the maxrows parameter like this:

```
<cfquery name="q" 
         datasource="#application.dsn#" 
         maxrows="100">
         SELECT * FROM events order by someDate Desc
</cfquery>
```

or you can use `TOP` or `LIMIT` in SQL itself.

Next comes your table.

To keep concepts simple I broke it up into a div and you can adapt it to your table or grid or whatever:

```
<cfoutput query="q" maxrows="18">
    <div>#firstcolumn# -  #secondColumn# - etc.</div>
</cfoutput>
```

The rest spill into a scrollable div.

```
<div style="width:500px;height:100px;overflow:auto;">
<cfoutput query="q" startrow="19">
    #firstcolumn# -  #secondColumn# - etc.
</cfoutput>
</div>
```

So then the main concepts of concern are:

- Your SQL query limited and ordered.
- Your first div (or table row or grid row) with `MAXROWS` set to 18
- Your scrolling div (or whatever) with `STARTROWS` set to 19

The rest falls into place.

Comment: This is not the solution he is asking for. All the records should be displayed in same div and the overflow height of the div should be as much to display 18 records. The rest records can be seen by scrolling the div scrollbar. @AnilKumarM I think this is what your question is?

Comment: @Pankaj I can't be sure of anything without seeing his code. So I gave him a useful answer based on something I had handy that was similar. I wasn't focused on the div part other than the scrolling element in the third code example.